# Log4j properties to print logs for java application running on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I am trying to print Logs from my java application which is hosted on Tomcat. In my log4 properties file I have set the following:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, JSON, TXT
log4j.appender.JSON=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSON.File=/var/log/tomcat7/dump.log
log4j.appender.JSON.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.JSON.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.JSON.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1

log4j.appender.TXT=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TXT.File=/var/log/tomcat7/dump_txt.log
log4j.appender.TXT.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.TXT.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.TXT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.category.com.val.mustard=INFO, TXT
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

The package name in the file where I am printing the logs is:

```
package com.val.mustard.platform.ed;


import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIServlet.class);
    logger.info("Inside is Valid action");
```

I have put logger.info in various functions in my APIServlet class. However I do not see it printed anywhere. Could some one guide me where I am going wrong in my log4j properties file

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: @PM77-1 Missed out pasting my question ! Edited it now

Comment: Is it being put into the log files? If it's not printing out to console, it might be because it's not listed in the root:
"log4j.rootLogger=INFO, JSON, TXT"
should be:
"log4j.rootLogger=stdout, INFO, JSON, TXT"

Comment: What is being put into the files? The log commands? No. What should I list in root?

Comment: In this case stdout will be catalina.out ?

Comment: Oops. Meant log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, JSON, TXT. It should be in catalina.out and spewed out on the console if tomcat is executing in the same thread (i.e. startup.sh).

Comment: @River info can be in CAPS or small right?

Comment: @River The order doesnt matter right? Last time you wrote stdout, info and now info, stdout

Comment: Order does matter. The first parameter is the default logging level as I recall. If I might make a recommendation, I would make sure you can at least log to stdout first and comment out the other appenders. Log4j might be throwing exceptions on you, which could be useful to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @River Tried it. Even with system.out it didnt work

Comment: Is SLF4J bound to Log4j (`slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.jar` in classpath)? Did you install Log4j 1.2 ()? Is Log4j reading your `log4j.properties` file? Are you sure?

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean by bound to log4j? In my setenv.sh file I have set: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/prop/log4j_ed.properties

Comment: Show us the logging libraries that are on your classpath.

Comment: @Andreas how do i check that?

Comment: Look in `WEB-INF/lib` inside your .war file. Don't you even know what you're packaging?

Comment: @Andreas I wasn't sure of what you meant. I have slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar ,slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar,slf4j-simple-1.7.0.jar , log4j-1.2.17.jar

Comment: Remove `slf4j-simple-1.‌​7.0.jar`. You can only have one binding. You should see a warning when you start Tomcat, informing you of that conflict. See [SLF4J user manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html), halfway down: *In your code, in addition to slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, you simply drop **one and only one** binding of your choice onto the appropriate class path location. Do not place more than one binding on your class path.*

Comment: @Andreas tried that as well. No difference

Comment: So I'll ask again:  Is Log4j reading your log4j.properties file? Are you sure?